# whose performance is better digital signatures (ECDSA) or Hash based signatures in case of ad-hoc networks

Tags: hash, ecdsa

i want to know performance wise which is better to provide message authenticity, ECDSA signatures or hash based signatures, although i have read the comparisons of ECDSA with RSA, but not found with hash based signatures. Can ECDSA signatures replaced  with Hash based signatures improves the message authenticity or not.

Answer (score 5):

ECDSA *is* a hash based signature, in that the data gets hashed, then ECDSA is performed on the hash (not the whole data)

When it comes to data verification there are three main approaches:

1. Straight hash (e.g. SHA-2-256)

   - The fastest option to verify
   - If you are only protecting against line corruption this is a valid choice.
   - Otherwise, requires that the hash/digest value be sent over a secure (from tamper) channel, because the tampered can easily transmit the digest along with the tampered document
   - Provides no proof of origin
2. HMAC (e.g. HMACSHA256)

   - Requires that both the sender and receiver share the secret key
   - Either the sender or receiver having the key stolen puts both sides at risk
   - Secret key needs to come from key agreement algorithms (ECDH) or be transmitted in secret (encrypted)
   - Proves the document came from someone with the shared secret.
3. Digital Signature (e.g. ECDSA, RSA signature)

   - The sender is the only entity with the private key, receiver needs public key (non-secret)
   - Public key can be embedded in an X.509 certificate to provide a notarized association of public key to the signer
   - Or the public key can be transmitted raw over a secure (from tamper) channel.
   - Provides strong assurances about the document origin, since they shouldn't share their private key.

All three options use a hash algorithm to reduce the original data, the rest of the algorithms are what do you do with that data. There's not really a standard definition of "secure", you have to say "secure against (something)". ECDSA provides more assurances than HMAC as long as the private key isn't shared. But if HMAC provides enough assurance it is probably faster on average (specialty hardware aside).

Comment: I roughly agree with this, but want to make a few points more explicit.  There is an implicit association between "hashed based signatures" and HMAC in the discussion.  With digital signatures, it is essential that the client verifies that public key is owned by the entity who is sending it.  With HMAC, the same process of checking the public key should have happened when the two parties agree on the shared secret.  The entire point of using HMAC over asymmetric options is for performance.  So normally you do the key exchange first and then HMAC from then on.